# Retreiving data from two different documents in firestore android to get users ID

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

In addition to the sender room side data, I want to get the id of the receiver room side to use it in the messages' deletion for the sender and receiver, but the messages duplicates in the RecyclerView. If anyone can find the error in the code. Thank you...

```
private fun setDataToAdapter(){
        firestore.collection("Chats").document(senderRoom!!).collection("messages").orderBy("time")
            .addSnapshotListener { value, _ ->
                if (!value?.isEmpty!!) {
                    messages.clear()
                    for (document in value.documents) {
                        val coMsg = document.data?.get("message").toString()
                        val coId = document.data?.get("senderId").toString()
                        val msgId = document.id
                        //Using Date
                        // Get Calendar
                        val calendarMap = document.data?.get("date") as Map<*, *>
                        val curTimestamp = calendarMap["time"] as com.google.firebase.Timestamp
                        val millis = curTimestamp.seconds * 1000 + curTimestamp.nanoseconds / 1000000
                        val ss = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault())
                        val netCal = Date(millis)
                        val msgTime = ss.format(netCal).toString()
                        // Get Day
                        val chatDay = document.data?.get("day").toString()
                        // Get Full Date
                        val fullDateStamp = calendarMap["time"] as com.google.firebase.Timestamp
                        val dateInMillis = fullDateStamp.seconds * 1000 + fullDateStamp.nanoseconds / 1000
                        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
                        val netAllDate = Date(dateInMillis)
                        val fullDate = sdf.format(netAllDate).toString()
                        val type = document.data?.get("type").toString()
                        firestore.collection("Chats").document(receiverRoom!!)
                            .collection("messages").orderBy("time").addSnapshotListener { value1, _ ->
                                if (!value1?.isEmpty!!) {
                                    for (document1 in value.documents) {
                                        val id = document1.id
                                        val coMsgT = SingleChatData(coMsg, coId, msgId, msgTime, chatDay, fullDate, type, id)
                                        messages.add(coMsgT)
                                    }
                                    recyclerView.post { // Call smooth scroll
                                        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount - 1)
                                    }
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: why not just set both usersId into data class? in this way each message contains userId of both users. also when you create a collection there is a document section so use it to store some meta data

Comment: Is it adding duplicates or is it adding the message over and over again?